# What are the Facebook app FBML 'profile.setFBML' arguments?

Tags: php, facebook, fbml

Okay so I've read the documentation, and I'm not quite sure what the arguments being passed are. I'm looking at the the listed example request:

`$facebook->api_client->profile_setFBML(NULL, 128009, 'profile', NULL, 'mobile_profile', 'profile_main');`

and thinking, where are they getting these arguments and what do they do?

Anybody have an explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This applies to the PHP library, other libraries may have their own syntax.

```
$facebook->api_client->profile_setFBML(session_key, uid, 'profile', 'profile_action', 'mobile_profile', 'profile_main');
```

**session_key** -  The session key of the user whose FBML you are setting. It is required for Web applications only when the uid is not specified, and hence is NULL in the example provided.

**uid** - The user ID for the user whose profile you are updating, or the page ID in case of a Page. If this parameter is not specified, then it defaults to the session user.

**profile** - The FBML intended for the application profile box that appears on the Boxes tab on the user's profile.

**mobile_profile** - The FBML intended for mobile devices.

**profile_action** - Deprecated and hence NULL in the example provided.

**profile_main** - The FBML intended for the narrow profile box on the Wall and Info tabs of the user's profile.

Comment: Looks slightly familiar: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/profile.setFBML

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but there are 4 **required** parameters in the beginning: api_key, call_id, sig, and v. Why the example doesn't need to pass them along?